# Sorting the data not working using angular One way binding when my objects keeps added dynamically by a signal R hub server to the angular web client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

I have call back function in the web client which keeps updated by the signal R hub and array of objects keep growing  with latest records and I need the data to sorted by Time which is not happening due to one way binding.When I change the code 2 way binding everything works.

Please advice how can I achieve using one way binding.

Java script code:

```
hubProxy.on('Callbackfunction', function (data) {
            $scope.Variables.push(data);
    });
```

Html Code:

```
<tr style="width:100%" ng-show="Variables != 'undefined' && Variables !='null' && Variables.length !=0" ng-repeat="item in Variables |orderBy: '-Time' track by $index" ng-class="getRowColor(item.Qualified)">
                                <td style="width:18%;">{{::item.Mnefgh}}</td>
                                <td style="width:10%;">{{::item.Value}}</td>
                                <td style="width:10%;">{{::item.Quali}}</td>
                                <td style="width:10%;">{{::item.Errjj}}</td>
                                <td style="width:22%"> {{::item.Time |date: "MM-dd-yyyy@HH:mm:ss"}}</td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: Will you share some more code of your controller? What is hubProxy? Have you tried to call `$scope.$apply()` in your callback?

Comment: Using  hubProxy we can access signal Connection methods its similar to calling a angular Factory. And in the code it has all the $ apply in place. And the code works fine and the data gets displayed correctly  if I remove sort option !!But when I add the sort option the data gets duplicated.